# Android sqlite flush WAL file contents into main database file

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to create a backup of my apps database contents and for most devices it works fine but a few have wal mode enabled by default which causes an issue. From everything I've read calling "pragma wal_checkpoint" should flush the contents of a -wal file into the main database file which is what I'm after. Flush the contents to main db file and then copy the db file for backup. I'm calling

```js
db.rawQuery("pragma wal_checkpoint;", null);
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: Executing `pragma wal_checkpoint;` will return a single row with three columns.  You can check those column values to determine exactly what the result of the call is.  For example, from the doc *The third column is the number of pages in the write-ahead log file that have been successfully moved back into the database file at the conclusion of the checkpoint.*

Comment: Running the command via sql command prompt works as expected but that command from inside my app does not.

Answer (score 7):

It's worked for me to flush wal file to main database.

```
        String query = "pragma wal_checkpoint(full)";
 
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int a = cursor.getInt(0);
            int b = cursor.getInt(1);
            int c = cursor.getInt(2);

        }
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        db.close();
```

Comment: what is db? There are several database objects and I can't find rawQuery()

Comment: @Phlip SQLiteDatabase object.

Answer (score 3):

[rawQuery()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) returns a cursor; the query is not actually executed until you try to read from the cursor.

To execute an SQL statement that does not return a cursor, use [execSQL()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[]%29) instead.