# How to manually perform checkpoint in SQLite android?

Tags: android, sqlite, mobile, checkpoint

I'm trying to create a backup of my sqlite database and I want to flush the content of the WAL file in the db first.

Here is my SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private Context mContext;
private static MyDBHelper mInstance = null;

private MyDBHelper(final Context context, String databaseName) {
    super(new MYDB(context), databaseName, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
   public static MyDBHelper getInstance(Context context) {

    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MyDBHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

  private void closeDataBase(Context context) {
    getInstance(context).close();
}

}
```

Now, my understanding is that after a checkpoint is completed, the mydb.db-wal file should be empty. Is that correct?

Here is what I've tried so far:
1.

```
    public Completable flushWalInDB() {
    return Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
            getInstance(mContext).getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("pragma wal_checkpoint;", null);
        }
    });
}
```

This doesn't throw an error but doesn't seem to do anything. After running this, I physically checked my mydb.db-wal file and had the same size. I also checked the db on the device and nothing was added in the database

After some digging around I found this 
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/30278485/2610933][1]
and tried this:

2.

```
    public Completable flushWalInDB() {
    return Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
            getInstance(mContext).getReadableDatabase().execSQL("pragma wal_checkpoint;");
        }
    });
}
```

When running this it throws an error:

```
unknown error (code 0): Queries can be performed using SQLiteDatabase query or rawQuery methods only.
```

And based on this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/19574341/2610933][1] , I also tried to VACUUM the DB but nothing seems to happen.

```
 public Completable vacuumDb() {
    return Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
            getInstance(mContext).getReadableDatabase().execSQL("VACUUM");
        }
    });
} 
}
```

Whats is the correct way of flushing the WAL file in the DB before creating a backup?

Thank you.

Comment: Regarding your first attempt with rawQuery, you need to do something like Cursor.moveToNext() to make it actually run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(2)` does copy all data from the WAL into the actual database file, but it does not remove the `-wal` file, and any concurrent connections can make new changes right afterwards.

If you want to be really sure that there is no WAL to interfere with your backup, run [PRAGMA journal_mode = DELETE](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode). (You can switch it back afterwards.)

Comment: Running just `PRAGMA wal_checkpoint;` does appear to delete the -wal and -shm files for me.

Comment: @CigaretteSmokingMan They are deleted when the last connection is closed. The longer your backup runs, the higher is the risk that other connections exist or are opened.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right! (Maybe add some edit to the post so that I can press the upvote button :))

Answer (score 2):

To manually add checkpont use **PRAGMA wal_checkpoint**, after searching for 2 hours following code worked for me -:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
String query = "PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(full)";

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int a = cursor.getInt(0);
    int b = cursor.getInt(1);
    int c = cursor.getInt(2);

}
if (cursor != null) {
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Referred from: [Android sqlite flush WAL file contents into main database file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69028219/514235)